# How can I use if login instead of if (!isset($submit))

Tags: php

I am using firstname, lastname and password to login into a particular page. Here is the login page code:

```
<form action="?page=welcome" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" target="_self">
   First name:
  <input name="firstname" type="text" id="title" size="26" maxlength="40" value="<? echo $firstname ?>"> 
  Last name:
  <input name="lastname" type="text" id="title" size="26" maxlength="40" value="<? echo $lastname ?>"> 
  Password:
  <input name="pwd" type="password" id="pwd" value="<? echo $pwd ?>"> 
  <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" class="button"> 
</form>
```

And here is the code for the welcome page:

```
<? include("dbconnection.php");?>
<?php
$phpver = phpversion();
$phpver = explode(".", $phpver);
$phpver = "$phpver[0]$phpver[1]";
if ($phpver != 41) {
$PHP_SELF = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
}
if (!ini_get("register_globals")) {
import_request_variables('GPC');
} 

if (!isset($submit)) {
show_login_form($firstname,$lastname,$password);
exit;
}

if (!($firstname&&$lastname&&$password)) {  

    echo "<br><br><center><span class='alertext' align=left>Please fill in all required fields to proceed.<br>";
echo '<a href="javascript: history.go(-1)">Go back</a></span>';
show_login_form($firstname,$lastname,$password);
exit;

} else {
$firstname=trim(addslashes("$firstname"));
$lastname=trim(addslashes("$lastname"));
$password=trim("$password");    

$log="SELECT * FROM application WHERE UCASE(firstname)=UCASE('$firstname') AND lastname='$lastname' AND password='$password'";
$query=mysql_query($log);
$info=mysql_fetch_array($query);

if (!$query or $info[0]==NULL) {

    echo "<br><br><center><span class='alertext' align=left>The login information is incorrect. Please try again.<br>";
echo '<a href="javascript: history.go(-1)">Go back</a></span>';
    show_login_form($firstname,$lastname,$password);
    exit;

} else {        

    $cat="SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE id='$info[0]'";
    $query2=mysql_query($cat) or die("Error".mysql_error);
    $info2=mysql_fetch_row($query2);

    $send="SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE id='$info[0]'";
    $info3=mysql_fetch_row($query3);            
    $id=$info[0];

    $sql_name = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE id='$info[0]'";
    $res_name = mysql_query($sql_name);
    $first_row = 1;
    while ($pinfo=mysql_fetch_array($res_name)) {           
        $explode = explode("-",$pinfo[name]);
    } ?>
<? }
 } 
?>`
```

This works fine. But I would like to have a third page as well. When I am using the same code on the third page (has a form and submit button) it is submitting the page automatically because of isset submit code used for login. I tried to use if login code instead of isset submit but have not succeeded. I would appreciate any comments or suggestions. Thank you.

Now I am trying to add page3 edit form on page2: Here is my edit form code that I moved to page2:
`<form name="form2" method="post" onSubmit="return checkForm(this);" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="?page=page3"> 
  <table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> 
    <tr> 
      <td width="16" height="38" bgcolor="#eaeaea"></td> 
      <td width="1280" valign="middle" bgcolor="#eaeaea"><span class="heading">Editing Application </span><br> </td> 
      <td width="16" bgcolor="#eaeaea"></td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr> 
      <td background="../img/box/left_line.jpg"></td> 
      <td> <table width="100%"  border="0.1" align="left" class="formtext"> 
          <tr> 
            <td class="formtext"><br> 
              First name:<span class="style4">*</span><br> 
              <input name="firstname" type="text" class="style5" id="firstname" value="<?php echo "$info[firstname]"; ?>" size="50" maxlength="100" /> 
              <br> 
              <br> 
              Last name:<span class="style4">*</span><br> 
              <input name="lastname" type="text" class="style5" id="lastname" value="<?php echo "$info[lastname]"; ?>" size="50" maxlength="100" /> 
              <br> 
              <br> 
              Are you?<span class="style4">*</span> 
              <SELECT name="applicant_type" class="style5" id="applicant_type"> 
                <OPTION VALUE="<? echo "$info[applicant_type]"; ?>"><? echo "$info[applicant_type]"; ?></OPTION> 
                <OPTION value="Student">Student</OPTION> 
                <OPTION value="Professor">Professor</OPTION> 
                <OPTION value="Professional">Professional</OPTION> 
              </SELECT> 
              <br> 
              <br> 
              Email Address:<span class="style4">*</span><br> 
              <input name="email" type="text" class="style5" id="email" value="<?php echo "$info[email]"; ?>"  size="50" maxlength="100" /> 
              <br> 
              <br> 
              Nation:<br> 
              <input name="nation" type="text" class="style5" id="nation" value="<?php echo "$info[nation]"; ?>" size="50" maxlength="100" /> 
              <br> 
              <br> 
              University (or corporate) name:<span class="style4">*</span><br> 
              <input name="college" type="text" class="style5" id="college" value="<?php echo "$info[college]"; ?>" size="70" maxlength="100" /> 
              <br> 
              <br> 
              Academic (or corporate) department:<br> 
              <input name="department" type="text" class="style5" id="department" value="<?php echo "$info[department]"; ?>" size="70" maxlength="150" /> 
              <br> 
              <span class="formnotes">(History, Mathematics, Psychology, Chemical Engineering, etc.)</span> <br> 
              <br> 
              Degree Major:<br> 
              <input name="major" type="text" class="style5" id="major" value="<?php echo "$info[major]"; ?>" size="50" maxlength="150" /> 
              <br> 
              <span class="formnotes">(Anthropology, Biology, Chemistry and etc.) </span> <br> 
              <br> 
              Degree pursued (or degree complete for non-students):<br> 
              <input name="degree" type="text" class="style5" id="degree3" value="<?php echo "$info[degree]"; ?>" size="55" maxlength="150" /> 
              <br> 
              <span class="formnotes">(Masters, PhD, etc.) </span> <br> </td> 
          </tr> 
          <tr> 
            <td> <input name="submit2" type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" class="button"> </td> 
          </tr> 
        </table></td> 
      <td valign="baseline" background="../img/box/right_line.jpg"></td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr> 
      <td><img src="../img/box/left_corner.jpg" width="16" height="14"></td> 
      <td background="../img/box/bottom_line.jpg"></td> 
      <td><img src="../img/box/right_corner.jpg" width="16" height="14"></td> 
    </tr> 
  </table> 
</form>`

When you click on submit button it takes me to page3 to set update Table data. Here is the code of page3 now:

```
`<? session_start();
$phpver = phpversion();
$phpver = explode(".", $phpver);
$phpver = "$phpver[0]$phpver[1]";
if ($phpver != 41) {
$PHP_SELF = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
}
if (!ini_get("register_globals")) {
import_request_variables('GPC');
}  

?>
<?php

include ("dbconnection.php");

    $query1 = "UPDATE TABLE SET ran = '$ran', firstname = '$firstname', lastname = '$lastname', applicant_type = '$applicant_type', email = '$email', 
    nation = '$nation', college = '$college', department = '$department', major = '$major', degree = '$degree' WHERE id='$id'";

    $result1 = mysql_query($query1) or die ('Could not run query: '.mysql_error());

    if ($result1) { echo "<br><br><center><span class='alertext'>Successfully modified!<br>(a copy of your information has been sent to you for your records)</span>"; ?>
 <center> 
<br> 
<span class="formtext">:: <a href="javascript: history.go(-1)">Go back</a> ::</span><br> 
<br> 
<span class="formtext">:: <a href='http://website.com'>Log out</a> ::</span>  <br> 
<?

}else { echo "<br><br><center><span class='alertext'>Error while modifying! </span>"; }

// sending confirmation messages

        if ($email<>NULL) 
        {
            $message = "Dear $firstname $lastname, \n\n";
            $message .= "REST of the Message.\n\n";

            $from = "From: Name <email@address.com> \n";
            $reply = "Reply-To: email@address.com ";
            $header .= $from . $reply;
            $sentmail = mail($email, "Subject", $message, $header);

        }
        if ($sentmail) 
        {

            //Copy of the message sent to Me

            $message = "Subject message sent by $firstname $lastname on ".date("Y-m-d")."\n\n";
            $message .= "REST of the Message\n";

            $message .= "Sincerely,\n";
            $message .= "Me \n\n";

            $from = "From: ".$name." <".$email."> \n";
            $reply = "Reply-To: ".$name." <".$email.">";
            $header = $from . $reply;
            $email2 = "email@address.com";
            mail($email2, "Subject", $message, $header);
}
?> 
</form>`
```

Comment: Can you please be more specific?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spent a minute or two and this is what I've understood from your question, You want to check if you've come from a *specific* page before moving on with that new page. There are couple of ways to achieve this:

> 1. $_SESSION

In the start of your old/new both pages write `session_start();` and then on your previous page store a value in sessions something like:

```
$_SESSION['check'] = true;
```

And on the next page apply a check like:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['check']){
// way to go
```

Likewise, you could use `$_COOKIE` too, depending on your requirements/condition.

> 2. $_GET

If you're passing from a url. Pass a query string from your previous page, something like:

```
$check = 1;
< a href = "newpage.php?check=<?php echo $check; ?>">Next Page</a>
```

And on the next page, fetch it like:

```
if(isset($_GET['check']){
// $chk = $_GET['check']; and blah
```

> 3. $_POST

Like you've already used to some extent:

```
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" class="button">
```

Above is the line copied from your code, Now:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['login'] == submit){
// making sure that you're redirected from login page blahh
```

Comment: Dear HawasKaPujaari,

Comment: Dear HawasKaPujaari, Thank you for your help. I have 3 pages. First one is the login page, second one is the page you see after login. And  I am passing to the third page from page two through a link. So I tried the Option 2 that you suggested but could not get it working. I am new to programming so I usually have hard time until I get something work.

Comment: @Nargis, _Dont give up until you get it done!_ What are you taking in your query string from page two? Copy paste it here and I will do my best to help!

Comment: On my page2 I have this link <a href='page3.php?id=<?php echo "$row[id]"; ?>'> Edit </a>. By clicking on this link I get to page 3. I am worried because when I copy paste page3 URL on a browser I can get to it with no password  or anything.

Comment: @Nargis, 1) Is `$row[id]` giving you the correct id on the next page? Have you tried to echo it before passing and even after receiving on `page3.php`? 2) The direct `putting the url and being able to see everything` is happening because you have not applied a _check_ in the start of your `page3.php` something like this should work: `if(isset($_GET['id'])) { //all of your page3.php content } else { echo "NO TRESPASSING";}`

Comment: Yes, I am getting a correct id. I will try what you have suggested. Thank you.

Comment: Do tell me how it goes. cheers

Comment: I tried did not work. It would just show a blank page. Here is my original code from page3 <form name="form" method="post" onSubmit="return checkForm(this);" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<?php
if (!isset($submit)) {
include("dbconnection.php");

$id = $_GET[id]; 
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE id='$id'";
$result2 = mysql_query ($query2) or die ('Could not run query: ' . mysql_error());
$info = mysql_fetch_array ($result2);
?>
Page Content </form>

Comment: @Nargis Why do you have a `<form>` tag? and that's not how you should have applied the check, try this: `<?php 
if (isset($_GET['id'])){ 
include("dbconnection.php"); 
$id = $_GET['id']; 
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE id='$id'"; 
$result2 = mysql_query($query2) or die ('Could not run query: ' . mysql_error()); 
$info = mysql_fetch_array ($result2); 
}?> `

Comment: HawasKaPujaari I tried your code but every time I put (isset($_GET['id'])) the URL was correct but my page content would not show. When I put back if (!isset($submit)) I could then see my page content. The page content is a form with number of inputs like <input name="firstname" type="text" class="style5" id="firstname" value="<?php echo "$info[firstname]"; ?>" > So the purpose of my page3 is to edit data that is already existing in the database. I know it's dragged long. Sorry about that. I will keep trying. Thank you for all the help. I appreciate that.

Comment: @Nargis Please note that if your page content is not showing it is because the if statement is not met. Which means you are not bringing the query correctly, It doesn't matter what the content is as long as you are applying the correct checks before it. Further more, your purpose of editing could be done on the same page you don't have to goto the next page. All you need is two different if statement checks one above your form and another below. If you can't get through this by tonight, I will demonstrate all the steps in my answer tomorrow morning as I'm at the hospital atm :-X cheers.

Comment: Thank you for your comments and advice. I will try that too. You mentioned hospital atm. I hope it is nothing serious. Thanks.

Comment: @Nargis how far did you get?

Comment: last night I tried to put my edit form from page 3 on page 2. The form looked okay with all the info from the database. Then I added a submit button to take to the page 3 where I had my set update table codes. When I tested I got echo message to say it was okay. But nothing would change in my database. Does it matter if the set update table codes are in a separate page? Thank you.

Comment: @Nargis That's totally fine, there is something wrong somewhere else, did you try to echo your query? And may I see the code on your edit page? Do you want me to put a sample data in my answer to demonstrate the behavior of  a EDIT form?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Since my code was long I added it to my original question. I added the edit form code that I moved to page2 and set update Table code on page3.

Comment: I was finally able to get my codes work. So the way I had split my codes into two pages was not working because on page2, edit page, I was missing an id echo. After adding that and rewriting the mysql code to `mysql_query("UPDATE application SET ran = '$ran'  WHERE id='$id'") 
or die('Could not run query: '.mysql_error());` It worked. Thank you for all your help. I would not think to do this without your help. So thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass another variable in through your query string and check for its existence. Or any other `$_POST`, `$_SESSION` type variable could help you have an if condition checking where you have come from. I hope I understood your question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

you could set a name of you submit button as "login" and then in the code test:

```
if(isset($_POST['login']) && $_POST['login'] == 'submit') {
    //process the form data
}
```